# import csv with php to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

I'm importing a csv file into a mysql table with php.
Now I'm going to put some lines as I have in the csv. csv has no header.

[image]

I leave the script of how I created the table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `Areceber` (
  `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `N_utente` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ano` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

now I will put the html script:

```
<form method="post" action="conexaoexcel1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_file" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and now the page conexaoexcel1.php:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$file_open = fopen($file,"r");
while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ";")) !== false)
{

    foreach ($csv as $key => $value){   

        $Id = str_getcsv($value[0], ',');       
        var_dump($Id);

    }
}
```

Now when I var_dump the first column it returns like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "7" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "8" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "9" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Up to the line that has the number nine it returns fine, but when it starts on the line that has the number 10, it only returns the number 1 without the zero and so on. Can you help solve the problem?

Comment: `$value` will already contain `10` for that column in that row, your mistake is that you are looking at the first character (or rather, byte) of it only, with `$value[0]`. And that you are calling `str_getcsv` at this point, makes no sense to begin with - `fgetcsv` already parsed the line into an array.

Comment: why are you doing ``$value[0]`` ? That'll return the first character of the string.

Comment: @CBroe But if I put `$Id = $value;`, it returns everything in the csv. When I insert into the database, it gives an error, because it tries to insert everything in the first column of the database

Comment: That's because your foreach loop goes over the values of _all_ columns of the line you just read. If you only want to work with the value of the first column - well then _don't_ loop over all of them, but just access the first one directly.

Comment: @C Broe I intend to insert the first column of the csv in the ´Id´ column of mysql, the second column of the csv in the `N_utente` column of mysql and the third column of the csv in the `Ano` column of mysql. Did you understand?

Comment: Can you show the actual CSV file contents, it may be the separators you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$csv` is already an array of data, and to output first column, use `$csv[0]` without looping.

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$file_open = fopen($file,"r");
while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ";")) !== false)
{

    $Id = $csv[0];       
    var_dump($Id);
}
```

Just check if your delimiter is right. If it's comma delimited change line

`while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ";")) !== false)`

to

`while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false)`

Otherwise it should work.

Comment: Did you check delimiter thing? It will return all data if its wrong delimiter you setted

Comment: I was using a comma and had to put the ;. It was just that. Thanks